# digital signature check and piracy

Tags: signature

Correct me if I am wrong, but if a byte of an app is changed then the signature of the app changes too. But in this library https://github.com/javiersantos/PiracyChecker in section verify signature there is written that we shoud save the signature in a variable and check if it is correct. I tried it and it works. But if we save signature inside a variable that means the app is changed which means the signatue is changed also and then it can't pass the check wright? So how is that possible?

how does a signature check works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand it. When a private key creates a certificate, then that certificate can be checked using the public key. But the piracy check included is using the public key or hash of the public key and NOT the whole apk digital signature.  When any part of the app is changed there is a high probability that the app digital signature changes. On the other hand, using a public key or hash of a public key inside the piracy check enables us to sign the app using our private key. The piracy check verifies if the app is signed with the equal public key or hash of the public key that is stored inside the code.